# Keep all parts of an accordion open

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/628qzvo6/) in my website and i wish keep the items open when I click in another, i mean, Brazil is already open on my list, and what i wanted are when the user click on Italy, don't collapse Brazil, just open Italy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$('.country > .countrybar').click(function() {

```
var checkElement = $(this).next();

$('.country > .countrybar').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('.country > .countrybar').addClass('active');   

if((checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('.country > .countrybar').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('fast');
}

if((checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('.country > .countrycontent:visible').slideUp('fast');
    checkElement.slideDown('fast');
}

if (checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;    
}
```

});
$('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').click(function() {

```
var checkElement = $(this).next();

$('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').addClass('active'); 

if((checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('fast');
}

if((checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent:visible').slideUp('fast');
    checkElement.slideDown('fast');
}

if (checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;    
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/628qzvo6/1/)? I've removed some code that checked if something else was visible. If so it would slideUp... Now it will not happen unless you click on it.

But did you write this code yourself? Or did you copy/paste it from somebody else?

```
$('.country > .countrybar').click(function() {

    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    //$('.country > .countrybar').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.country > .countrybar').addClass('active');   

    if((checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        //$(this).closest('.country > .countrybar').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('fast');
    }

    if((checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        //$('.country > .countrycontent:visible').slideUp('fast');
        checkElement.slideDown('fast');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;    
    }
});
$('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').click(function() {

    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    $('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').addClass('active'); 

    if((checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('fast');
    }

    if((checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent:visible').slideUp('fast');
        checkElement.slideDown('fast');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;    
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a monster with some parts copied and some parts written.

Comment: @EderAugusto, okay try out the code and check the fiddle in the question. That is what you want right?

Answer (score -2):

Check my code :  https://jsfiddle.net/628qzvo6/

```
$('.country > .countrybar').click(function() {

    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    //$('.country > .countrybar').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.country > .countrybar').addClass('active');   

    if((checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        //$(this).closest('.country > .countrybar').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('fast');
    }

    if((checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        //$('.country > .countrycontent:visible').slideUp('fast');
        checkElement.slideDown('fast');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('.country > .countrycontent')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;    
    }
});
$('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').click(function() {

    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    $('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').addClass('active'); 

    if((checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('.countrycontent > .leaguebar').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('fast');
    }

    if((checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent:visible').slideUp('fast');
        checkElement.slideDown('fast');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('.countrycontent > .leaguecontent')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;    
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle and effect ?

Comment: Open this fiddle and check the effect

Comment: Yes! Do you saved?

Comment: Is the same link that i put on the question, nothing change. Perhaps you dont save, do you?